# How to check whether an array contains a substring within a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of strings:

```
string_array = ['memberid', 'membershiptype', 'date']
```

Now I need to check whether or not this array contains `'id'`, and I want it to return true.

I know I can do `string_array.include? 'memberid'`, but I need to find a substring within that string of `'id'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`string_array.any? { |e| e.include? 'id' }`

`any?` returns true if any of the elements in the array are true for the given predicate (i.e. the block passed to `any?`)

Comment: No problem. If it answered your question, please mark it as the answer.

Comment: string_array.any?{|x| x['id'] } and !string_array.grep(/id/).empty? also works.